# How to grant/revoke access tomultiple users on multiple google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I own 2 spreadsheets. One Master and one template.

On Master, I add patients and create a new spreadsheet for this client as a copy of the template. At this moment I give the client Edit access to this file.

This worked fine. But now I have to add staff and each of them needs Edit access to each copy of the template and Read access on the master.

Staff members come and go. I wonder what is the best way to simplify authorization.

Now I loop thru all files and give/revoke for each document. This is not performing in the long run.

Can I apply permission to a folder? or to a group and just add/remove staff to this security group? I'm new to the google apps script, hope you can show me the right path.
**EDIT:** Now I'm here
[image]

I need staff member to have access to view the master and edit any of the copies of the template. Also, I need people from outside the organization to have access to edit their own copy of the template.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Also, I develop all this under my own Gmail account, now I have to move this into the orbit of the organization. What are the steps?

Answer (score 1):

### In your case, the easiest might be to create a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/) and share your spreadsheet with it

When the staff members "come and go" you can simply add and remove them from the Google group and do not need to touch the spreadsheet's sharing settings.

Btw, when you create a copy of your spreadsheet programamtically, you can retrieve the editors of the current spreadsheet with [getEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geteditors) and assign them to the copied spreadsheet with [addEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditorsemailaddresses)

Comment: Thanks, I was not thinking of this type of group, but maybe it works. I'll wait to see more options.

Comment: Could you help me with my actualization? thanks